# $scope updates not shown in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

$scope doesn't seems to sync with updates in Angularjs.

I update my time values (myst and myet) using ui.bootstrap.timepicker, then when I display `userscheds[index]` using `alert(JSON.stringify($scope.userscheds[index]));`, only the original values are displayed. Something I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated

See my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nBkQkLCQx3riqOopeQy1) or code below

**update #1**

Comment from @dgig to remove `this.` in `ng-model="this.myst"`. Changed to `ng-model="myst"`

But my $scope still not shown with the updates done

html modal

```
<div class="container" ng-app="appUserSchedule">
<div ng-controller="CtrlUserSchedule" >

<div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in userscheds">{{x.week_day}} {{x.time_start}}-{{x.time_end}}
            <span ng-click="ctrl.showModal($index)" style="cursor:pointer;">Edit</span>
            <span ng-click="ctrl.removeItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;">Delete</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->  
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContent.html">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <timepicker ng-model="myst" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <timepicker ng-model="myet" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveUserScheduleEntry()">Save</button>
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module("appUserSchedule", ['ui.bootstrap']); 
app.controller("CtrlUserSchedule", function($scope,$http,$location,$modal) {

$scope.ctrl = this;

$http.get('userschedule.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.userscheds = data.userschedules;

    //console.log(data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("No data found..");
});


  // Show modal 
  this.showModal = function (index) {

  var modalInstance;

  modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
    controller: 'CtrlUserSchedule',
    scope: $scope 
  });

  objts   = new Date($scope.userscheds[index].datetime_start);           
  objte   = new Date($scope.userscheds[index].datetime_end);       

  $scope.myst = objts;
  $scope.myet = objte;


      // Save User Schedule Entry details after making a change, then close modal    
      $scope.saveUserScheduleEntry = function() { 

      // Displays original value, but where are my updated values?
       alert(JSON.stringify($scope.userscheds[index]));

         $http.put('userschedule.json',index).success(function(eventsuccess){
       }).error(function(err){
           /* do something with errors */
       });

       modalInstance.close();
     };   

}
```

json

```
{
"userschedules":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "week_day":"Monday",
     "datetime_start":"2016-03-08T08:00:00-05:00",
     "datetime_end":"2016-03-08T12:00:00-05:00",
     "time_start":"08:00",
     "time_end":"12:00"
  },
  {
     "id":21,
     "week_day":"Monday",
     "datetime_start":"2016-03-08T13:00:00-05:00",
     "datetime_end":"2016-03-08T17:00:00-05:00",
     "time_start":"13:00",
     "time_end":"17:00"
  }, ...
```

Comment: What does your alert show?

Comment: `{"id":1,"week_day":"Monday","datetime_start":"2016-03-08T08:00:00-05:00","datetime_end":"2016-03-08T12:00:00-05:00","time_start":"08:00","time_end":"12:00","$$hashKey":"object:3"}` if I edit/save the first entry in my data. And that's after I've updated the data and saved. So it shows the original data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not sure. You have a lot going on - if you look at the modal sample here (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), they have two separate controllers - you have only one in your plunker. I'm not even able to get the modal to pop up in your plunker. Maybe you have more in your real code, I'm not sure. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Thanks @dgig . To pop the modal, click on Edit, it should work